# fcntl file lock example not working

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to workout a toy example of locking files in python 3.4.3, however I'm not getting the expected results.

I have two scripts, script1.py, and script2.py:

```
#script1.py
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import fcntl

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"script_id": [0], "val1": [0], "val2": [0]})
df.to_pickle("data.pkl")

for i in range(500):
    f = open("data.pkl", "rb+")
    while True:
        try:
            # lock if unlocked
            fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(0.01)
    df.loc[i, :] = np.concatenate([np.array([1]), np.random.sample(2)])
    time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0, 0.05))
    pickle.dump(df, f)
    # unlock when done
    fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
    f.close()
```

Second script is very similar:

```
import pickle
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import fcntl

f = open("data.pkl", "rb")
while True:
    try:
        fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
        df = pickle.load(f)
        fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
        f.close()
        break
    except:
        time.sleep(0.001)

for i in range(500, 1000):
    f = open("data.pkl", "rb+")
    while True:
        try:
            # lock if unlocked
            fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
            break
        except:
            time.sleep(0.01)
    df.loc[i, :] = np.concatenate([np.array([2]), np.random.sample(2)])
    time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0, 0.05))
    pickle.dump(df, f)
    # unlock when done
    fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
    f.close()
```

The idea is that two scripts should read and write to a same file, with some artificial delays.

Each script adds one random row to a dataframe loaded from data.pkl it should sum up to 1000 rows.

I first run `script1`, then as fast as I can I run `script2`. I end up with `500 + n` rows dataframe where `n` is the number of appended rows before I run script2.

Why I use pandas and numpy in a toy example? I will have a similar usage case, so I want to make sure it works with objects I'll be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, in case someone else encounters this problem.

I created a second file `lock.lck` which is locked while I do operations and writing to `data.pkl` file. After writing to `data.pkl` is done, lock gets released.

```
# script1.py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import fcntl

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"script_id": [0], "val1": [0], "val2": [0]})
df.to_pickle("data.pkl")

for i in range(500):
    with open("lock.lck", "r") as f_lock:
        fcntl.flock(f_lock, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0, 0.05))

        df = pd.read_pickle("data.pkl")
        df.loc[i, :] = np.concatenate([np.array([1]), np.random.sample(2)])
        df.to_pickle("data.pkl")
```

Now the second script:

```
# script2.py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time
import fcntl

for i in range(500,1000):
    with open("lock.lck") as f_lock:
        fcntl.flock(f_lock, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
        time.sleep(np.random.uniform(0, 0.05))

        df = pd.read_pickle("data.pkl")
        df.loc[i, :] = np.concatenate([np.array([2]), np.random.sample(2)])
        df.to_pickle("data.pkl")
```